# How do I get rid of spaces for fields that are grouped?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report where I'm grouping on many different fields. The Gender field has large spaces in between the values. How do I remove those spaces? All answers are very appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first thing I would do is make sure you have no trailing spaces or carriage returns in your data (you could `TRIM` the spaces out for example).

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that already but still spaces.

Comment: try right-click the fields in the tablix, the actual placeholder not the textbox (so the text inside the text box). Then set the background property to something obvious like green and look at the report. This will show you were the actual data ends, if you find the data spans several lines then you may have line feeds etc in that are no visible, TRIM will only remove spaces, not CRLF etc.I assume in the report design the rows are all a single line high? If this does not help, show the report design.